# std::result_of failing for void return type

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

I am trying to use SFINAE to create function call wrappers using std::result_of to get the return type of the function. Small sample to reproduce the problem:

```
void test(int) {}

template<typename T, typename... Args, typename R = typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<R>::value, int>::type* = nullptr>
int test2(R& ret_param, Args... args)
{
    T* test_call = test;
    ret_param = test_call(args...);
    return 0;   
}

template<typename T, typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type>::value, int>::type* = nullptr>
int test2(Args... args)
{
    T* test_call = test;
    test_call(args...);
    return 0;   
}

int main()
{
  test2<decltype(test)>(1);
}
```

compiling this with gcc 4.9.2 results in:

```
68:26: error: no matching function for call to 'test2(int)'
68:26: note: candidates are:
46:5: note: int test2(R&, Args ...) [with T = void(int); Args = {}; R = int; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_void<R>::value), int>::type* <anonymous> = 0u]
46:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'int&'
56:5: note: template<class T, class ... Args, typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type>::value, int>::type* <anonymous> > int test2(Args ...)
56:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
55:142: error: function returning a function
55:142: note: invalid template non-type parameter
```

The problem then is that somehow "typename std::result_of::type" evaluates to a function returning a function? What is the correct way to use SFINAE to force overload resolution to pick a different function if the return type of the template function is void? Worth mentioning that in the reverse case where the test function returns an int. Additionally, if the enable_if is removed for the std::is_void resolution it will work in this case (but obviously then both functions will be valid resolution if there is a return type and compilation will fail when it picks the one not expecting a return value).

Comment: As a start, `decltype(test)` is a function type, and you're binding that to `T`, which in the enabling logic is treated as a return type.

Comment: I would use `class` instead of `typename`, and I would avoid those multi-hundred character lines. Try to split up things naturally so as to be readable.

Comment: Not following, my understanding is that std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type is the return type of the function T if called with the arguments Args... which is what I am using in the enabling logic.

Comment: `T(Args...)`, e.g. `int(char, double)`, is a function returning `T` and with formal arguments `Args...`. Oh wait. `std::result_of` is defined to expect that. Sorry.

Comment: Well, sorry about the "sorry": you need to form T_ref(Args...) where T_ref is T&. See the `std::result_of` requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need to form `T_ref(Args...)` as the argument to [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

The following compiles. I've applied a few simplifications and reformatting.

By the way I don't think this is a good idea. Instead just have **different names** for the two functions. They do need different arguments, after all. Explicit is good. Implicit is bad.

```
#include <type_traits>      // std::(enable_if, result_of)

void test(int) {}
int foo() { return 0; }

template<
    class T,  class R, class... Args,
    class T_ref = T&,
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_void<
            std::result_of_t<T_ref(Args...)>
            >::value
        >::type* = nullptr
    >
int test2(R& ret_param, Args... args)
{
    static_assert( std::is_same<
        R,
        std::result_of_t<T_ref(Args...)>
        >::value, "!" );
    T* test_call = foo;
    ret_param = test_call(args...);
    return 0;
}

template<
    class T, class... Args,
    class T_ref = T&,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_void<
            std::result_of_t<T_ref(Args...)>
            >::value
        >::type* = nullptr
    >
int test2(Args... args)
{
    T* test_call = test;
    test_call(args...);
    return 0;   
}

int main()
{
    test2<decltype(test)>( 1 );

    int result;
    test2<decltype(foo)>( result );
}
```

Comment: Generally agree about implicit is good vs explicit is bad but abstractly they are doing the same thing so I would like them to have the same name otherwise it would complicate a bunch of code elsewhere. Thanks for the example, is there someway that I can take T by ref initially and avoid that extra template parameter? This works great, just trying to make it look prettier than it really is :)

Comment: You can just write `T&` in the `result_of` and not add an extra template parameter.

Comment: I used your nice idea in this snippet
https://godbolt.org/z/M3vh68Khz
as a mean to find an answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75396460/893406

Answer (score 1):

If you accept to pass the test function as a parameter, you don't need all that boilerplate:

```
void test(int) {}
int test(double) { return 0; }

template<typename R, typename... Args>
int test2(R(&f)(Args...), R& ret_param, Args... args)
{
    ret_param = f(args...);
    return 0;   
}

template<typename... Args>
int test2(void(&f)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    f(args...);
    return 0;   
}

int main()
{
    test2(test, 1);
    int r;
    test2(test, r, .0);
}
```

Deduction and overloading will do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't pass the function as a parameter as I only have the declaration of the function. Passing the actual function will just give me linker errors. Can only use the decltype of the function.

Comment: @Grahalt Ok, you put a definition in your example, so I couldn't know that. I'm sorry.